# hamburger centered in toolbar with default height

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

When we set a drawer with an hamburger, the hamuburger is in center_vertical of the toolbar, but if we change the height of the tool bar the hamburger does not moove, how do I put it in the center (vertical)?

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    assert drawer != null;
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    assert navigationView != null;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ----//----

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
        android:background="#303f9f"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use minHeight attributte

```
android:minHeight="40dp"
```